# Can we have dynamic group by clause in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have one stored procedure...which has one parameter: `@subCustName`.
This stored proc has one select statement with `group by custName, subCustName`

Ex:

```
SELECT custName, subCustName,sum(membership)
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
GROUP BY
custName, subCustName
```

If parameter `@subCustName` is `'ALL'`, I dont want to group by subCustName.

How do I acheve that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Group on a CASE statement?

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @custName = 'all' THEN '' ELSE custName END AS custName,
    subCustName, sum(membership)
FROM  
    CUSTOMER_TABLE
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN @custName = 'all' THEN '' ELSE custName END, subCustName
```

Another example in my answer here: [SQL Server 2005/2008 Group By statement with parameters without using dynamic SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784283/sql-server-2005-2008-group-by-statement-with-parameters-without-using-dynamic-sql/1784364#1784364)

Comment: I am getting following error :- Column 'custName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you using this *exact* query I posted?

Comment: I donno..I had tried the same query before posting this question...But when I copied ur query it'w working..What's happeneing :). anyway thanks Alot....

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
IF (@subCustName = 'ALL')
    SELECT custName, subCustName, 1
    FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
ELSE
    SELECT custName, subCustName, sum(membership)
    FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
    GROUP BY custName, subCustName
```

or you can build query dynamically

Comment: There is another way: Create a separate stored procedure that does the grouping. This may actually be a better option since you're overloading the semantics of customer name which could lead to serious trouble if you ever get a customer named `'all'`