# How to group a select based on Input from Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, grouping

I'm looking to group a case based on the input of a parameter.

I Have a main select statement and need to group it by date depending on the daterange type selected by the user.

For example the user has four options in the parameter :

- Month_Quarter
- Date_Month
- Date_Week
- Date_Year

And based on the the selection in the parameter the select will be grouped using the date name function associated with the selected parameters for example : Month_Quarter = DATENAME(QUARTER,STARTDATE)

I tried using an if statement but this didn't seem to work. Anyone able to help

update : Attempt

```
IF @daterange = 1 

select ......

from ......
```

group by  DATENAME(QUARTER,start_date)

```
IF @daterange = 2 

select ......

from ......
```

group by  DATENAME(month,start_date)

Comment: You probably just need `CASE` instead of `IF`, but to be certain you need to give a concrete example.  Please include the query you have tried, the error message you got, example source data and example expected results.  If you're uncertain what should be in such an example, please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I gave an idea of my query above. When I put this into Visual Studio and refresh the dataset , the parameter input screen pops up and the dataset returns empty

Answer (score 0):

using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT
    CASE @param WHEN 'Month_Quarter' THEN DATENAME(QUARTER,STARTDATE),
    CASE @param WHEN 'Date_Month' THEN DATENAME(month,start_date) 
AS Tim_QUARTER
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    CASE @param WHEN 'Month_Quarter' THEN DATENAME(QUARTER,STARTDATE),
    CASE @param WHEN 'Date_Month' THEN DATENAME(month,start_date) END
```

you can use `ELSE` statement in your case.

add another column name to your `select` statement and `group by` clause.

Examples are here [SQL Server 2005/2008 Group By statement with parameters without using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784283/sql-server-2005-2008-group-by-statement-with-parameters-without-using-dynamic-sql/1784364#1784364)

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to help when you cut out the code that might be relevant...

@HasanFathi has given an option that uses `CASE` within the SQL to mimic your `IF` statements.  An alternative is to use a `WHERE` clause to only return results if the param is set appropriately, then `UNION ALL` for each of the various combinations.  This should help generate better execution plans for each version of the query...

```
SELECT DATENAME(QUARTER,start_date), blah FROM foo WHERE @dateRange = 1 GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH  ,start_date), blah FROM foo WHERE @dateRange = 2 GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
-- etc, etc, etc

ORDER BY x, y, z  -- Order the result of the UNION, not each component
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope below solution will help you. I have also shared the input and output of those below:

/*
•Month_Quarter {@PassedValue: '3'  @selectedOption: 'Month_Quarter',
   Output: [{   SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product3' }, 
           { SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product4' }]
•Date_Month {@PassedValue: 'June'  @selectedOption: 'Date_Month',
   Output: { SaleDate: '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product2' }
•Date_Week  {@PassedValue: '35'  @selectedOption: 'Date_Week',
   Output: [{ SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product3' }, 
            { SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product4' }]
•Date_Year  {@PassedValue: '2017'  @selectedOption: 'Date_Year',
    Output: [ { SaleDate: '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product2' },              { SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product3' },              { SaleDate: '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', Name: 'Product4' }]
*/

declare @PassedValue varchar(50) = '2017',
        @selectedOption varchar(50) = 'Date_Year'

create table #temp
(
    Name varchar(50),
    SaleDate datetime
)

insert into #temp(Name, SaleDate)
select 'Product1', '20160501'
union 
select 'Product2', '20170601'
union
select 'Product3', '20170901'
union
select 'Product4', '20170901'

If(@selectedOption = 'Month_Quarter')
Begin
    select SaleDate, Name from #temp 
    where @PassedValue = DATENAME(QUARTER, SaleDate)
    group by SaleDate, Name
End
Else If(@selectedOption = 'Date_Month')
Begin
    select SaleDate, Name from #temp 
    where @PassedValue = DATENAME(MONTH, SaleDate)
    group by SaleDate, Name
End
Else If(@selectedOption = 'Date_Week')
Begin
    select SaleDate, Name from #temp 
    where @PassedValue = DATENAME(WEEK, SaleDate)
    group by SaleDate, Name
End
Else If(@selectedOption = 'Date_Year')
Begin
    select SaleDate, Name from #temp 
    where @PassedValue = DATENAME(YEAR, SaleDate)
    group by SaleDate, Name
End

drop table #temp
```